# Whats the strategy for docker overlay vip balancing?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I'm looking into docker swarms load balancing methodologies. There's information on DNS Round Robin which means if i have 5 nodes, the routes will target containers in the following order: 1-2-3-4-5-1-2-3

What is the determining factor for the default VIP-based endpoint-mode?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/#customize-an-overlay-network

**Note:**

*While NGINX is **NOT** involved, this is the type of documentation i would expect from docker:*
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html#nginx_load_balancing_methods

Comment: I don't have an answer but I might be able to set you down an investigation path. I believe that under the hood Docker Swarm is using LVS. LVS has a number of load balancing methods documented at http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/IPVS. There is also a blog article at https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2016/07/29/service-discovery-and-load-balancing-internals-in-docker-1-12/ that shows some debug output from LVS which suggests the mode is rr (Round Robin). Though, I'm not sure if this is tunable or where it is documented (like you imply, it may not be documented at all).